# Using pull-down resistor, but driving pin high by connecting to Vcc directly

Tags: input, pins, pulldown

I have a device that I know very little about.

I have access to Vcc and Gnd pin there, and it operates on +5V.

I need to drive its input pin high or low depending on a switch, that's UART RX input.

I have optoisolator between my MC and that device. Driving LED in optoisolator on my end is done, and I would prefer not to change it.

Here is a schematics from the device's side

[image]

I am afraid, that when optoisolator will be on, +5V will go directly into Rx pin with possibly too much current, and damage it.
The device is expensive, and this is supposed to work in production. And, as mentioned before, that's all I know about the tech side of the device.

Basically, I luck a knowledge of how to work with pull-downs and input pins.
I can, of course, change schematic on another side to use pull-up here, but I would like to learn this.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the input 5V tolerant?

Comment: I suppose, Vcc is +5V, I run 5V into it at 9600 baud rate a couple of times before I realized that current could be a problem

Comment: It might help if you tell us what MCU you are using...

Comment: Are you wanting/able to measure input impedance with a series R and variable supply?

Comment: Inputs are typically high impedance and will draw minimal current. If it's designed to accept 5V signals, they aren't going to also design it to draw so much current that it damages itself when 5V is applied to it. That would be evil. R1 is a different story. Obviously don't make it so low that it draws so much current that it damages the opto. If you're paranoid that someone might connect something other than 5V to the opto then that is a different issue altogether.

Comment: @DKNguyen Do you say it should be normal to just connect it directly to 5V as in my schematics above? 
The whole of this question arises for me from the stm32 datasheet where they say pin can sink up to 25mA and my lack of knowledge to understand the consequences of this.

Comment: @TarasBilynskyi When you apply a fixed voltage to something, as an MCU output pin will, the load then determines how much current will be pulled based on that voltage. A constant voltage will not try to shove its maximum current capability into the load. That 25mA is the capability of the MCU pin, not what it will do. The most common use of that number is driving LEDs which require more than ~0mA to do something but requires less than ~20mA to do something useful.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you. Keeping schematics as it is, except will pay attention to R1.

Comment: @TarasBilynskyi What is your background? That was pretty basic. Similar to if a table is rated for 500lbs, it doesn't mean that everything put on the table suddenly weighs 500lbs to load the table down that much. Some types of ratings are for maximum capability while others are for what the device will actually do. A voltage supply rated for 5V@5A means that it actually puts out 5V and can output up to 5A if required. A current supply rated for 5A@5V means that it actually will try to output 5A under all circumstances and can produce up to 5V, if necessary to force that 5A through the load.

Comment: Your input could handle connection to either of those supplies since it is rated for 5V. The voltage supply would provide no more current than the input draws, which by design should be safe for itself. The current supply would try to shove 5A into your input which would be bad, but it can't since it cannot produce more than 5V to do so and your input can handle that. However, if it was a current supply rated at 5A@10V, that would be bad since the input is not designed to take 5A or 10V, but the supply would produce >10V to try and push 5A through.

Comment: The first one to exceed the input's rating fries it. In this case it would be voltage since a high impedance input would take a phenomenal amount of voltage to force 5A through it. SO although the current supply can't produce enough voltage to actually force 5A through the input, it would produce a voltage greater than the input's max 5V in an attempt to get as close to 5A as possible.

Comment: I am a software developer, electronics is my hobby for not so long. I understand that the voltage supply's goal is to provide voltage and current there is a tool to achieve that. The same with the current supply and voltage being a tool. But my knowledge is segregated, and so - luck of confidence. Especially in the internals of MC pins configured as inputs, have some feeling that those pins can be connected to ground and so a short may happen